# elastic beanstalk: incremental push git

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I would like to push incremental changes to the AWS Elastic Beanstalk solution I get the following:

```
$ git aws.push

Updating the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment None...
Error: Failed to get the Amazon S3 bucket name
```

I've already added `FULLS3Access` to my AWS users policies.

Comment: You appear to have two EB CLI versions going on here. `git aws.push` is from the 2.x version of the CLI, and is not included in the 3.x version. `eb config` is a 3.x command. You will probably need to manually change the `.elasticbeanstalk/config` (not config.yml) to conform with your current state. Either that or uninstall 3.x.

Comment: Ah ok, that gives some insight. How to do incremental push to eb with CLI 3.x then?

Comment: Sadly, 3.x currently doesn't support incremental.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue today and here are the steps I followed to investigate :-

1. I modified line no 133 at .git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py to print the exception like

except Exception, e:
    print e
* Please make sure of spaces as Python does not work in case of spaces.

2. I ran command git aws.push again 
   and here is the exception printed :-

BotoServerError: 403 Forbidden
{"Error":{"Code":"SignatureDoesNotMatch","Message":"Signature not yet current: 20150512T181122Z is still later than 20150512T181112Z (20150512T180612Z + 5 min.)","Type":"Sender"},"

The issue is because there was a time difference in server and machine I corrected it and it stated working fine.

Basically the Exception will helps to let you know exact root cause, It may be related to Secret key as well.

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the boto-library (related [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=579067)). If you are on **ubuntu/debian** try this:

*Remove old version of boto*

```
sudo apt-get remove python-boto
```

*Install newer version*

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install -U boto
```

**Other systems (e.g. Mac)**

*Via easy_install*

```
sudo easy_install pip
pip install boto
```

*Or simply build from source*

```
git clone git://github.com/boto/boto.git
cd boto
python setup.py install
```

Had the same problem a moment ago.

***Note*:**

I just noticed your environment is called *none*. Did you follow all instructions and executed `eb config`/`eb init`?

**One more try:**

Add `export PATH=$PATH:<path to unzipped eb CLI package>/AWSDevTools/Linux/` to your path and execute `AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh` maybe something is wrong with your repository setup (notice the *none* weirdness). Other possible solutions:

- Doublecheck AWSCredentials *(maybe you are using different Key IDs / Wrong CredentialsFile-format)*
- Old/mismatching versions of `eb` client & `python` (check with `eb -v` and `python -v`) *(current client is [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk/cli/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.4.zip))*
- Use amazons [policy validator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/policies-policy-validator.html) to doublecheck if your AWS User is allowed to perform all actions

If all that doesn't help im out of options. Good luck.

Comment: $ sudo brew remove python-boto
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python-boto

Comment: So i guess there is no boto installed?! i have refined my answer. brew should have installed pip already. let me know if that works now.

Comment: I tried both, via easy_install and from source, but without success.. still get the same error. I've entered eb init and eb conifig too..

Comment: Don't know why it says env. None... In eb config EnvironmentName: is set to a name.

Comment: The git aws.config helped me forward. I did not do this step.

Comment: But git aws.config asks "dev_tools_endpoint:" what should this be?

Comment: $ git aws.push
Updating the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment My First Elastic Beanstalk Application...
Error: Failed to create the AWS Elastic Beanstalk application version

Comment: PS: And there is no "mac" folder in AWSDevTools only linux

Comment: `dev_tools_endpoint:` just press enter. my bad with the mac folder, use the linux one. it's just a shellscript anyway.

Comment: No still the same error...    
$ git aws.push Updating the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment My First Elastic Beanstalk Application... Error: Failed to create the AWS Elastic Beanstalk application version

Comment: Is there a place where errors are logged in detail?

Comment: `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git aws.push` & `eb ... --debug`